# Identify this (non) solenoid component

Tags: components, identification

I got this component from someone clearing out their garage. At first I thought it was a solenoid but the ‘pin’ section doesn’t move and there is no spring on the outside of the component.

I haven’t had a chance to ask a professional or to hook it up to power, but I was hoping it could be identified. The component has no identifiable markings or writing, and after checking the print on the wiring it is specifically about the wire not the component. See pictures attached.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: item picture 1]
[image: item picture 2]

Comment: Might be a small pump of some kind - the "pin" seems to be a tube, and there is a vent type thing on the other side. Alternatively it could be a solenoid with an actuator inside the tube.

Comment: Have you measured resistance between the two pins? If it seems to be a resistance, you could try connecting it to a single AA battery momentarily and see if anything happens.

Comment: Maybe an electromagnet if the pin is fixed.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Don’t have a multimeter on me so I just stuck the wires on a battery - nothing happened. At all, no noise, no movement, nothing. Maybe it’s busted or the AA just isn’t enough to get it going?

Comment: Given it doesn't seem to have any moving parts, you could try placing a sewing needle or unfolded paper clip (steel/stainless type) in the hole and seeing if power has any affect on it - to test if it is an electromagnet.

Comment: Looks like a shaded pole AC solenoid something like the water pumps used in expresso makers using a spring loaded diode pumped current to make a water pump oscillating at line frequency and very noisy.  But given the air intake its possibly an air pump for aquarium tanks.  ( Am I close in my guess?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a solenoid air valve, used in blood pressure meters. [Here's](https://www.ebay.com/itm/KOGE-KSV05A-DC3V-Mini-Electric-DC-Solenoid-Valve-Normally-Open-For-Gas-Air-Valve/122013250818?_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D49476%26meid%3Df9e00faeb3b745638b372341f14d510a%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D263278112824&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m2219) another example:-

[image]

[image]